# How to get SendBytes in SharpPcap OnPcapStatistics event?

Tags: c#, .net, winpcap, sharppcap

I'am using the sample :

> [SharpPcap Example 11: statistics](http://sharppcap.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=sharppcap/sharppcap;a=blob;f=Examples/Example11.Statistics/Example11.Statistics.cs;h=c677ac75e1727e011f333bf942bdf48e4d724142;hb=HEAD)

the OnPcapStatistics event only gives me the received bytes, how could i get the uploaded ( send) bytes ?

> total += (ulong)e.Statistics.RecievedBytes;